# Produce separate scatterplots for all columns with all columns for a Python-dataframe with empty cells

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I try to automate the correlation plotting of a large dataframe. The goal is to plot each column with another column in a scatter with a regression line through it. Each column represents a different variable and a column can potentially have empty cells, integer and string values (try code and working example are below)

Example code:

```
Age     Height   Weight  Sex
21      180      54      M
56      171      65      V
23      NaN      84      V
NaN     195      71      M
42      165      67      V
84      167      93      M
12      NaN      88      M
31      152      73      V
NaN     184      NaN     V


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_subset = pd.DataFrame({"Age": [21,56,23,np.nan,42,84,12,31,np.nan], "Height": 
[180,171,np.nan,195,165,167,np.nan,152,184], "Weight": [54,65,84,71,67,93,88,73,np.nan], "Sex": 
['M','V','V','M','V','M','M','V','V']})

print(df_subset)
col_choice = ["Age", "Height", "Weight"]

for pos1, axis1 in enumerate(col_choice):   # Pick a first col
    for pos2, axis2 in enumerate(col_choice[pos1+1:]):   # Pick a later col
        plt.scatter(df_subset.loc[:,axis1], df_subset.loc[:,axis2]) #scatter plot
        a, b = np.polyfit(df_subset.loc[:,axis1], df_subset.loc[:,axis2], 1) #determining parameters for regression line
        x = df_subset.loc[:,axis1]
        plt.plot(x, a*x + b) #regression line on scatter-plot
        plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Now that I updated it a little bit, my final question is/are: How to deal with empty cells in the dataframe when scatterplotting. For each scatterplot separaretely, the rows with empty cells should be excluded from the dataframe to be able to plot it I guess.. And then secondly, how to plot a regression line when dealing with both string-variables or one string/one numeric variable?

Comment: `df_subset[[df.columns[pos1],df.columns[pos2]].dropna()` is a two-column dataframe with all the na-rows removed. so that deals with the first part of the question. for a regression with categorical values on the x-axis there is really no good answer. what would you like the plot to look like? I guess a bar chart would make more sense than a scatter plot, and I think you could drop the regression line altogether....

Comment: Also, check out if seaborn `pairplot` is enough for your needs... It can be slow on large datasets, but it might be worth looking into..... https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

Comment: And where exactly would you place the .dropna() codeline in the example code? If you place it in an answer, I'll accept and vote it up if it works.. Oh and thanks for the seaborn alternative, that can come in handy as well but not sure how it'll perform for a dataset with e.g., 100 columns and 10000 datapoints.. The regression line is there for correlation purposes, sometimes it's interesting to do it on categorical variables as well (by converting them to categorical numerical values if needed for regression-line plotting)

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you want the regression on 'sex' to look? It makes no sense to me currently....

Comment: Hmm jep, you may be right. I just wanted to see what would happen, maybe some categorical variables in my dataset show correlation with others. I just wanted to test it and make the code applicable for both numerical and categorical values. The scatter works for both but the regression-line does not, which sucks then because I've to turn it off while scattering categorical values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import numpy as np 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

    df_subset = pd.DataFrame({"Age": [21,56,23,np.nan,42,84,12,31,np.nan], "Height": 
[180,171,np.nan,195,165,167,np.nan,152,184], "Weight": [54,65,84,71,67,93,88,73,np.nan], "Sex": 
['M','V','V','M','V','M','M','V','V']})   
    print(df_subset)  

    col_choice = ["Age", "Height", "Weight"]

    for pos1, axis1 in enumerate(col_choice):   # Pick a first col     
        for pos2, axis2 in enumerate(col_choice[pos1+1:]):   # Pick a later col         
            df = df_subset[[axis1,axis2]].dropna()         
            print(df)         
            plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1]) #scatter plot         
            a, b = np.polyfit(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1], 1) #determining parameters for regression line         
            x = df.iloc[:,0]         
            plt.plot(x, a*x + b) #regression line on scatter-plot         
            plt.show()
```